# how to include context path specified in the location to the resources loading from proxied url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

We have a similar nginx configuration

```
server 1 
  location /abc{
  proxy_pass server2;
}

server 2 

location /abc/bcd/efg {
proxy_pass app1/; 
}
```

in browser when we type `server1/abc/bcd/efg/app`

the html page of app1/app is been loaded but the absolute url specified in the html page is not using the location context path`/abc/bcd/efg`

instead it uses `server1/app/dummy.css` like this

what is the configuration need to be updated to add the location attribute to get included in the respective resource url.

i want to route the css and js of a proxied application using the configured location path.